# Ordenar alfabeticamene en un arbol binario

Tags: c, lista, ordenamiento

Es un arbol binario que tiene la finalidad de guardar nombres en orden alfabeticamente sin embargo no estoy seguro de que estoy pasando el parametro correctamente. Siento si el codigo esta un poco largo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct nodo
{
  char nombre[10];
  struct nodo *izq,*der;
};

void inserta(struct nodo*insercion,struct nodo*elemento);
void imprime(struct nodo *p);
void borra(struct nodo *p);

int main()
{
  int i,n;
  char name[10];

  struct nodo *raiz,*temp;

  raiz=NULL;
  printf("Teclea nombres, seguido por un caracter no numerico\n");
  do{   
    gets(name);
    getchar();
    {
      temp=(struct nodo*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
      temp->der=NULL;
      temp->izq=NULL;
      strcpy(temp->nombre,name);
      if(raiz==NULL)
      {
        raiz=temp;
      }
      else
      {
        inserta(raiz,temp);
      }
    }
  }

  printf("Listo\n");
  printf("Nombres impresos en orden\n");
  imprime(raiz);
  borra(raiz);
}

void inserta(struct nodo*insercion, struct nodo*elemento)
{
  struct nodo*avanza,*nuevo;

  avanza=insercion;

  if(avanza!=NULL)
  {
    if(strcmp(elemento->nombre,avanza->nombre)>0)
    {
      if(avanza->der!=NULL)
      {
        inserta(avanza->der,elemento);
      }
      else
      {
        avanza->der=elemento;
        return;
      }
    }
    if(strcmp(elemento->nombre,avanza->nombre)<=0)
    {
      if(avanza->izq!=NULL)
      {
        inserta(avanza->izq,elemento);
      }
      else
      {
        avanza->izq=elemento;
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Has detectado algun problema en tu código? ¿Qué es lo que le pasa? Si tu programa no funciona como esperas tal vez el error no tengas que buscarlo únicamente en la función `inserta`...

Comment: USando el debugger note que al introducir un segundo valor, la raiz tambien toma ese valor

Comment: El codigo que has puesto dudo mucho que compile.... el do no tiene su correspondiente while. Te has confundido al copiar el código